# How to create a general plot for this problem

Tags: plotting

I would like to have some ideas about each customer depending on how many products he sells each month.

We have created a new feature `X` based on some other features.

We have noticed that, in most case, when Feature `X` decrease the amount of product sells decrease as it is illustrated with the figure bellow

[image]

For each customer, I have a similar plot (i.e in the most cases when the feature decrease buying product decrease).

How can I generalize this analysis for getting one global plot?

Answer (score 1):

I think your data has three variables: `customer_ID`, `number_of_products_sold`, and `feature_x`. Time is not, as far as I can tell from your description, relevant.

To get all three relevant variables plotted in one figure, start with the data for a single customer and show `number_of_products_sold` versus `feature_x` as a scatter plot (removing the time aspect). This scatter plot with, say, circles for each data point, could be extended to multiple `customer_ID`s by overlaying scatter plots with different marker types.